# copy paste text and image both to clipboard in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uipasteboard

I am working on an app where I want to copy some text and image and allow user to paste it anywhere. I know it is done using UIPasteboard and I have implemented copying of image but now I want to copy image and text both and then let user paste it. There can be several images and text messages which can come in any order. It is like a paragraph being written with text and images. Is this possible? Can someone suggest me how can I achieve it?

Regards
Pankaj

Comment: Is there any particular problem ? The general `UIPasteboard` description is available at official documentation.

Comment: I want user to type in some text and select few images from a list of images. It is like writing a paragraph with images and text.

Comment: That is still a general description. Do you need to let users to paste selected "paragraphs" into other applications ? Copying complete "paragraph" (or several ?) or only selected range of text and inline images ? What's about formatting of the copied text & images ?

Comment: @A-Live, I see a legit question here.  It might be better rephrased as:  "I'm using UIPasteboard to copy text from my app <line of code here>, but I want to copy images, too.  How do I use pasteboard to copy many objects?".

Comment: @danh you might be better than me at reading minds, I still don't understand where his roadblock is.

Comment: @danh is right. This is what I wanted to explain. I am sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1):

You can put anything you wish in the pasteboard, including multiple entries like of type `UIPasteboardTypeListString` and another of type `UIPasteboardTypeListImage`, and even another of type `@"My Made-Up Type"`.  Think of it as a shared mutable dictionary.

It's up to the receiving application to understand what to do with them.

Comment: Since iOS8, placing both images and text on the pasteboard results in the image(s) being pasted into Mail, but the text is discarded. (Either on their own, works fine)

Does anyone have a way to avoid that?